# Getting various SSLExceptions when running loadtest on an SSL enabled URL call (HTTPS)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, weblogic, ssl-certificate

We are running a load test of API calls to an SSL secured URL and we get several SSLExceptions while performing load tests. We have had our SSL certificates setup in our Weblogic JVM trust store and we don't see these issues when calling the HTTPS URL normally.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: <UNKNOWN ALERT: 194>
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: insufficient_security
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate expired
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: export_restriction
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unobtainable
```

Any leads on what the root cause maybe? I am trying to figure what could possibly cause these errors to come so randomly during our performance tests.

Comment: You need to post the complete stack traces in each case, but 'certificate expired' seems pretty clear.

Comment: These erros happen intermittently. The SSL certificates do work. But we get these myriad SSL exceptions so randomly that we are unable to derive any pattern from these.